# What is the purpose of assigning global variables to local variables inside a Constructor and setters in the same class?

Tags: java, constructor, setter

```
 public class EmpRecord {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public EmpRecord(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

In above Class, Setters are there to set the value for those two Private variables, but what is the purpose of doing the same inside the Constructor? What is difference between those two - assigning global variables to local inside a Constructor and also in Setter?

Comment: There are no global variables here. I wouldn't include setters. This class doesn't have an empty constructor, so it isn't a bean. Exactly what are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not case of **global and local variable**.(It's parameterized constructor).

Whenever you're creating instance of class at same time you're assigning values to it's fields.

If you don't do that then you have to call setter methods of field through instance variable.

```
public EmpRecord(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
}
```

explanation:

whenever you create instance of class **EmpRecord** like:

```
EmpRecord obj = new EmpRecord("foo", 111);
```

Here you're directly assigning value **foo to EmpRecord.name** and and **111 to EmpRecord.id**.

If you don't do this then if you wish the assign value then you've to do:

```
obj.setId(111);
obj.setName("foo");
```

*So it's nothing more than assigning values to fields at instance creation time.*

Answer (score 3):

In constructor, you are initiating the field.

In the setter, you are overwriting the field.

For a single instance, you can initiate it only once, while you can `set` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If you initialise in the constructor, then once the object is created, you won't be able to change the variables' values. What if you want to override the initial values at some later point of time? You'll need setters for that since the variables are private.